# Upgrade TOM API function : GetListMultimediaTypes into Web 8.5 Core Service function

Tags: core-service, web8.5, tom.net

Which is the function in Web 8.5 Core Service for getting the all multimedia types because we need to replace the TOM API function : `GetListMultimediaTypes`

Thanks

Shekhar

Comment: It may help the question if you say *why* you want to replace this with the Core Service version. Also, what methods you’ve already tried or investigation you’ve already done and why it wasn’t successful. Are you struggling to find the API documentation? If so, then add that to the question and someone will be able to help. P.S. it wasn’t me with the downvote, but if you add the additional info then I’ll make sure to up vote it! :)

Answer (score 6):

Let me try to understand what you need to achieve. 
According to TOM.NET API documentation, `GetListMultimediaTypes` is used to retrieve all multimedia types defined in system (.jpg, .png, .doc....)

So, I guess you want to retrieve same data using Core Service. You can get this data by using `MultimediaTypesFilterData`

```
    MultimediaTypesFilterData filter = new MultimediaTypesFilterData
    {
        BaseColumns = ListBaseColumns.Extended,
    };

    XElement mmtypes = client.GetSystemWideListXml(filter);
```

Result of executing this code is shown bellow:

```
<tcm:ListMultimediaTypes Managed="65544" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:0-1-65544" Title="Gif image" Icon="T65544L0P0" MIMEType="image/gif" FileExtensions="gif"></tcm:Item>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:0-2-65544" Title="Jpeg image" Icon="T65544L0P0" MIMEType="image/jpeg" FileExtensions="jpg,jpeg,jpe"></tcm:Item>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:0-3-65544" Title="Png image" Icon="T65544L0P0" MIMEType="image/png" FileExtensions="png"></tcm:Item>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:0-4-65544" Title="Word document" Icon="T65544L0P0" MIMEType="application/msword" FileExtensions="doc"></tcm:Item>
</tcm:ListMultimediaTypes>
```

So you see that you can retrieve this data in similar way. Also, if you are new to Tridion Stack Exchange, please update your question as Jonathan suggested so that people can provide more relevant answers according to exact requirements.

Comment: The `ListBaseColumns.Extended` makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Please reference below your for more. The Core Service has methods for retrieving lists of Content Manager items.

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-973CC313-C411-4737-8263-F04D4378331C